# alert en c# cambio de mensaje de error

Tags: c#

como cambio un exception de un try catch por un mensaje personalizado proyecto de asp .net core
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! asp del lado del servidor, lo que sea del lado del cliente.. tu api devuelve un error y el cliente la procesa...

Comment: para el codigo tenes un editor disponible en esta pagina

Comment: codigo en foto ens poco visible tenes un editor de codigo disponible en esta pagina

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static bool ValidarUserLDAP(string strRutaLDAP, string strUsuario, string strPsw, out string exception)
  {
            exception = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                //AuthenticationTypes typeAutentication = (AuthenticationTypes)"tipoAutentificacionLdap".AppConf(AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                var typeAutentication = (AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                using (DirectoryEntry objRoot = new DirectoryEntry(strRutaLDAP, strUsuario, strPsw, typeAutentication) { })
                {
                    string filter = "(objectClass=users)";
                    try
                    {
                        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(objRoot, filter);
                        search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
                    {
                        exception = string.Empty;
                        return false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception )
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No se puede autenticar debido a que no se encuentra correctamente configurada la autenticación favor comunicarse con el administrador del aplicativo.");
              
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
        {
            exception = string.Empty;
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            exception = exe.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

este código me muestra el comentario pero sigue saliendo una parte que muestra la ruta y lo quiero quitar que solo sea ese mensaje que esta ahí

Comment: En la pregunta, debes pulsar en _editar_. Esta es la zona de respuestas.

Comment: @padaleiana no puede hacerlo hasta que se resuelva la edición pendiente (que por cierto era tuya :-) ) con más votos favorables.  Supongo que por eso está pegando más código en respuestas en lugar de conseguir editar su pregunta.

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/322460)

Comment: @masterguru de hecho, si el OP acepta la edición, automáticamente se acepta tal edición (sin importar la cantidad de usuarios que la aceptaron / rechazaron), y podrá hacer su propia edición. Tal vez siquiera vio la edición pendiente. (Sí, repetí mucho "edición") :)

Comment: @padaleiana Vaya, pues no lo sabia, gracias por la aclaración... entonces me callo y a ver si el OP despierta y se da cuenta :-)